# WebApp in iPad have and access over Native Camera

Tags: ipad, web-applications, camera

WebApp wanted to develop in the iPad, WebApp will be running as a kiosk

now wanted to give button which opens a Native camera.

i wanted to directly open the Native camera,  not much keen to use it

Any Solution please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add native camera support to any web app on Android, iOS or Windows Phone 8 very easily with BridgeIt: http://bridgeit.mobi. It's a simple javascript api that allows you to access native mobile features.

Comment: Thanks, i have develop the Same flow, from WebApp i have called my Custom Native App. Now After Task is Completed i wanted to switch back to the old WebApp. Is it possible to Achieve please guide me or show any workaround to achieve it.

Comment: A native app can transfer back to the webapp on supported platforms, which is what BridgeIt does. When you've completed a task in the BridgeIt utility app, the app opens a URL to the originating web app url and a provided callback in javascript is triggered for the web app  to handle data passed back to it.